# Can someone explain to me how does this code work?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int array[101]={0},i=0,n;
    printf("Enter numbers: \n");
    for (int i=0; i<1000 ;i++){
      do {
          scanf("%d",&n);
          if ((n<0 || n>100) && n!=-1) {printf("Numbers must be between 0 and 100!\n");}
      } while ((n<0 || n>100) && n!=-1);
    if (n==-1) break;
    array[n]++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<=100;i++) {
      if (array[i]!=0) printf("Number %d occurs %d times.\n",i,array[i]);

    }
}
```

This program lets the user input a lot of number between 0 and 100. Then it calculates how many each time number occured, for example if user inputs 3 3 3 1, the program will write "Number 3 occurs 3 times Number 1 occurs 1 times" .. The code works but I don't understand why it works and how. Especially this last for loop. Can someone break down this code to me and explain how it works step by step? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

array variable (int array[101]) is an array that counts the times the number i has been introduced. All its positions are initialized to zero. For example, array[5] contains the times the number 5 has been typed. Each time is typed, its value is incremented.

This instruction increase the number:

> array[n]++;
>   where n is the number typed

the last loop iterates trough the array and display only the numbers that has been typed (array[i]!= 0)

> for (i=0;i<=100;i++) {
>      if (array[i]!=0) printf("Number %d occurs %d times.\n",i,array[i]);
>   }